# Changing password of postgres user led imidiate prompt of wrong password without providing a password

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, change-password

So I forgot the password of the `postgres` user on my PostgreSQL server. I then changed all the `md5` settings in the `pg_hba.conf` file to `trust`, restarted the server and then changed the password of the postgres user using `ALTER USER postgres...`. Now I changed the `trust` settings back to `md5`, restarted the server again, but when I now want to perform `psql -U postgres` it immediately returns an error:

> psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
> password retrieved from file "/root/.pgpass"

without asking me to enter any password. The `.pgpass` file has the following line in it:

`*:*:*:postgres:SOME_HASH`

**EDIT:**

Somehow this only appears when logging in as `root` to my server... With my other user it works just fine...

Comment: It should be md5, not mb5

Comment: Sorry. this was a typo here. changed it

Comment: Well, then remove the wrong password from `/root/.pgpass`

Answer (score 0):

The immediate solution is to remove the `.pgpass` file that contains the wrong password. If you didn't create that file yourself, odds are that pgAdmin did that for you when you told it to save the password.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify '-W', then psql will prompt you for a password and ignore the .pgpass file.  But why not fix .pgpass, or if you aren't using it, then remove it?